# Got an error of "Cannot start service processor: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380"

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to test run the backend of my sawtooth project within a Ubuntu vm with the command: `sudo docker-compose -f sawtooth-default.yaml up`

And while it was running, an error comes up, which is as follows:

> ERROR: for todo-tp  Cannot start service processor: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/taskledger/startup": permission denied: unknown

> ERROR: for processor  Cannot start service processor: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/taskledger/startup": permission denied: unknown

I have searched and tried many different solutions that I can find online, but none of them can solve this error specifically as far as I can see. The docker version is 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~18.04.3 and the Ubuntu version is 18.04.6 LTS Bionic. I also include the yaml file and the Dockerfile for reference.

sawtooth-default.yaml file

```
version: "2.1"

services:

  settings-tp:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:1.0
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-default
    depends_on:
      - validator
    entrypoint: settings-tp -vv -C tcp://validator:4004

  validator:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:1.0
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default
    expose:
      - 4004
    ports:
      - "4004:4004"
    # start the validator with an empty genesis batch
    entrypoint: "bash -c \"\
        sawadm keygen && \
        sawtooth keygen my_key && \
        sawset genesis -k /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv && \
        sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch && \
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
          --endpoint tcp://validator:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
        \""

  rest-api:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:1.0
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-default
    ports:
      - "8008:8008"
    depends_on:
      - validator
    entrypoint: sawtooth-rest-api -C tcp://validator:4004 --bind rest-api:8008

  shell:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-all:1.0
    container_name: sawtooth-shell-default
    depends_on:
      - rest-api
    entrypoint: "bash -c \"\
        sawtooth keygen && \
        tail -f /dev/null \
        \""

  processor:
    image: todo-tp
    container_name: todo-tp
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
        - no_proxy
    volumes:
      - .:/taskledger
    depends_on:
      - shell
      - validator
    entrypoint: |
     /taskledger/startup -vv tcp://validator:4004
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

RUN echo "deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/stable xenial universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
 && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8AA7AF1F1091A5FD \
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y -q \
    apt-transport-https \
    build-essential \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    python3-aiodns=1.1.1-1 \
    python3-aiohttp=1.3.5-1 \
    python3-aiopg \
    python3-async-timeout=1.2.0-1 \
    python3-bitcoin=1.1.42-1 \
    python3-cbor \
    python3-cchardet=2.0a3-1 \
    python3-chardet=2.3.0-1 \
    python3-colorlog \
    python3-cov-core \
    python3-cryptography-vectors=1.7.2-1 \
    python3-cryptography=1.7.2-1 \
    python3-dev \
    python3-grpcio-tools=1.1.3-1 \
    python3-grpcio=1.1.3-1 \
    python3-lmdb=0.92-1 \
    python3-multidict=2.1.4-1 \
    python3-netifaces=0.10.4-0.1build2 \
    python3-nose2 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-protobuf \
    python3-psycopg2 \
    python3-pycares=2.1.1-1 \
    python3-pyformance \
    python3-pytest-runner=2.6.2-1 \
    python3-pytest=2.9.0-1 \
    python3-pytz=2016.10-1 \
    python3-requests \
    python3-secp256k1=0.13.2-1 \
    python3-setuptools-scm=1.15.0-1 \
    python3-six=1.10.0-1 \
    python3-toml \
    python3-yaml \
    python3-yarl=0.10.0-1 \
    python3-zmq \
    software-properties-common \
    python3-sawtooth-sdk \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to run it successfully without errors within host system (Windows 10 Pro) but still, due to circumstances, this won't solve the problem entirely due to the need of using virtual machine, not host, as the end goal. I'm guessing it has something to do with Ubuntu permission?

Comment: Which service in your `docker-compose.yml` file has the problem; are the remainder necessary to demonstrate the issue?  In your Dockerfile it doesn't look like you `COPY` the application code in or set a `CMD` to run it, are these lines missing?

Comment: I have identify that the `processor` service could be the cause of the problem based on the errors pop up. No changes was done on the Dockerfile and it is as is based on the lab/tutorial I'm following. Same goes for the yaml file.